# What is rospy.sleep for?

Tags: rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Really confused here. I want to delay certain publishing of messages to a topic for about 1-2 seconds. Can rospy.sleep help? My code already works fine, but I need the delay since I cannot put any delays in the Arduino/rosserial because it gives a lost sync error. Can someone please help? I've been doing this for 2 weeks and no solution so far. Here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import rospy
import time

from std_msgs.msg import Int32  
from sensor_msgs.msg import Range

flags = Int32()

class warning_flag():
    def __init__(self):
        self.aIR_FR = None
        self.aIR_FL = None
        self.dIR_front = None
        self.dIR_BR = None
        self.dIR_BL = None
        self.sonic = None
    
    def aIR_FR_callback(self, aIR_FR_msg):
        print "Analog IR Right Range: %s" % aIR_FR_msg.range
        self.aIR_FR = aIR_FR_msg.range
        self.warn()

    def aIR_FL_callback(self, aIR_FL_msg):
        print "Analog IR Left Range: %s" % aIR_FL_msg.range
        self.aIR_FL = aIR_FL_msg.range
        self.warn()
    
    def dIR_BL_callback(self, dIR_BL_msg):
        print "Digital IR Left Range: %s" % dIR_BL_msg.range
        self.dIR_BL = dIR_BL_msg.range
        self.warn()

    def dIR_BR_callback(self, dIR_BR_msg):
        print "Digital IR Right Range: %s" % dIR_BR_msg.range
        self.dIR_BR = dIR_BR_msg.range
        self.warn()

    def dIR_front_callback(self, dIR_front_msg):
        print "Digital IR Range: %s" % dIR_front_msg.range
        self.dIR_front = dIR_front_msg.range
        self.warn()

    def sonic_callback(self, sonic_msg):
        print "Ultrasonic Range: %s" % sonic_msg.range
        self.sonic = sonic_msg.range    
        self.warn()
        
    def warn(self):
        sonic_zone = 0.3
        aIR_FR_zone = 0.2
        aIR_FL_zone = 0.2
        dIR_front_zone = 0
        dIR_BR_zone = 1
        dIR_BL_zone = 1

        if (self.aIR_FR > aIR_FR_zone and self.aIR_FL <= aIR_FL_zone):
            print "Turn right"
            flags.data = 2
    
    elif (self.aIR_FR <= aIR_FR_zone and self.aIR_FL > aIR_FL_zone):
            print "Turn Left"
            flags.data = 3

        elif (self.aIR_FR <= aIR_FR_zone and self.aIR_FL <= aIR_FL_zone):
            if ((self.sonic > sonic_zone and self.dIR_front != dIR_front_zone) or
        (self.sonic <= sonic_zone and self.dIR_front != dIR_front_zone)):    
                if (self.dIR_BR != dIR_BR_zone and self.dIR_BL != dIR_BL_zone):
                    print "Stop"
                    flags.data = 5
                else:    
                    if (self.aIR_FR > self.aIR_FL):
                        print "Turn Right"
                        flags.data = 2
                    else:
                        print "Turn Left"
                        flags.data = 3

        elif ((self.sonic > sonic_zone and self.dIR_front == dIR_front_zone) or
        (self.sonic <= sonic_zone and self.dIR_front == dIR_front_zone)):
                if (self.dIR_BR == dIR_BR_zone and self.dIR_BL == dIR_BL_zone):
                    print "Back off"
                    flags.data = 4
            #put delay here
            if (self.aIR_FR > self.aIR_FL):
                       print "Turn Right"
                        flags.data = 2
                    else:
                        print "Turn Left"
                        flags.data = 3
                else:    
                    if (self.aIR_FR > self.aIR_FL):
                        print "Turn Right"
                        flags.data = 2
                    else:
                        print "Turn Left"
                        flags.data = 3

        elif (self.aIR_FR > aIR_FR_zone and self.aIR_FL > aIR_FL_zone):
            if (self.sonic > sonic_zone and self.dIR_front == dIR_front_zone):
        print "Advance"
        flags.data = 1                
        else:   
        if (self.dIR_BR == dIR_BR_zone and self.dIR_BL == dIR_BL_zone):
                    print "Back off"
                    flags.data = 4
            #put delay here
            if (self.aIR_FR > self.aIR_FL):
                        print "Turn Right"
                        flags.data = 2
                    else:
                        print "Turn Left"
                        flags.data = 3
                else:    
                    if (self.aIR_FR > self.aIR_FL):
                        print "Turn Right"
                        flags.data = 2
                    else:
                        print "Turn Left"
                        flags.data = 3
         
def main():
    rospy.init_node('sensor_pub_sub_node')
    warn_pub=rospy.Publisher('Warnings', Int32, queue_size=1000)
    warning = warning_flag()
    aIR_FR_sub=rospy.Subscriber('aIR_FR', Range, warning.aIR_FR_callback)
    aIR_FL_sub=rospy.Subscriber('aIR_FL', Range, warning.aIR_FL_callback)
    dIR_BR_sub=rospy.Subscriber('dIR_BR', Range, warning.dIR_BR_callback)
    dIR_BL_sub=rospy.Subscriber('dIR_BL', Range, warning.dIR_BL_callback)
    dIR_front_sub=rospy.Subscriber('dIR_front', Range, warning.dIR_front_callback)
    sonic_sub=rospy.Subscriber('ultrasound', Range, warning.sonic_callback)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        warn_pub.publish(flags.data)
       rate.sleep()

if __name__=='__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302408/what-is-rospy.sleep-for?/) by [Nelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/36679/nelle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rospy sleep is another way like time.sleep to pause a thread from running at its full possible rate and taking unnecessary resources. A `while true` would take up **alot** of resources otherwise.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/36679/nelle/) on 2018-09-04**:
Can I use rospy.sleep in my code then? Just to pause for a few seconds? I want to delay the publishing of a message for a topic.

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2018-09-04**:
Sure, its an option if you just want to pause

**Comment by [Nelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/36679/nelle/) on 2018-09-04**:
I tried to put it in my code and it doesn't seem to work. It keeps coming back to back off even if my sensors for other movements were triggered.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-09-07**:
I don't understand your problem exactly, you might have to be more precise (and possibly do it in another question)